# How to inject dependencies into resolveRedirectTo of routeProvider in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-rootscope

Please help me understand with an example how to inject $rootScope into $routeProvider's resolveRedirectTo. I checked the official documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) but I couldn't find a working example to understand it better. Please help

I tried the below code but it is not getting called.

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    resolveRedirectTo: function($rootScope, $http){
                console.log("externalUrl : " + $rootScope.externalUrl);
                window.location = $rootScope.externalUrl;
            }
    })
```

Comment: Could you please check the console if there are any errors? Is the controller being undefined legal?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it in this form in order to be able to inject dependencies

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    resolveRedirectTo: ['dependency1','dependency2',function(dependency1, dependency2){
            .....
        }]
})
```